# Count the number of items per hour, then find the average of the result

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I'm trying to build a query to find average number of music tracks played per broadcast hour for a given day.

I have a table that logs when a track was played, based on a datetime value (created field).

So I need to count how many entries, or tracks, where logged per hour.

Then with the hourly totals, find the average.

So far I have this, but wondered if it is correct?

```
SELECT AVG(a.total) FROM (
    SELECT HOUR(created) AS hour, COUNT(id) AS total 
    FROM `music_log` r 
    WHERE DATE(created) = DATE( DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY) ) group by HOUR(r.created)
) a
```

I got to admit, I formulated that from another post on stackoverflow, and don't understand what the **a** and **r** mean/reference.

I would like to know if I have this right, so I can expand query to cover a quarter (3 months) results.

Comment: Looks pretty good. Note that DATE(created) cannot use an index. A and r are aliases. R isn't strictly necessary, but a is.

Comment: Oh right. So created can't be an index in the table. Is that right? I've not had any issues previously.

Comment: created can be indexed. DATE() cannot take advantage of that index. If possible (and sometimes it just isn't), it's better to write the query such that the index can be utilised, e.g. : `WHERE created BETWEEN '2016-04-02 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-02 23:59:59';`

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the average without a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(created), HOUR(created) ) as average
FROM `music_log`
WHERE QUARTER(created) = 1 AND YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW()) ;
```

This calculates the total count and the number of hours without the need for a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

As Strawberry says, it looks like I'm on the right track. Thanks Strawberry.

To expand this, and just in case it helps anyone else, I've included the query to cover a quarter, in this case the first quarter of the current year....he says hoping there's nothing else wrong with my query :)

```
SELECT AVG(a.total) FROM (
    SELECT DATE(created) as day, HOUR(created) AS hour, COUNT(id) AS total
    FROM `music_log`
    WHERE QUARTER(created) = 1 
    AND YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW()) 
    group by DATE(created), HOUR(created)
) a
```

In order to calculate it correctly, I needed to group the hourly results by Date and Hour.

In the previous query in the question, it was only grouping by Hour. Which is fine if the Average calculation is over just a single day, but when you expand that beyond a day, the results become incorrect. This is because it will add the total of both occurrence of 11pm, for example, then work out the average.

Hope that helps...or if I've made a mistake, I hope someone picks up on it ;)